# How to intercept the external hyperlinks in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, hyperlink, external

I have the situation, where two web sites using the same data (main version and mobile). So in some pages of main version I have the internal links like www.domain.com/link1...
But when mobile version uses the same hyperlink it directs the user context to main site but i need to intercept that request and handle it and to redirect the user where I need in case of mobile version.

Let's say in main version of site in www.domain.com/about/strategy.aspx (webforms) page I have an absolute url to www.domain.com/services/item.aspx?Id=1256 and it is ok.
But when I got same page on mobile.domain.com/about/strategy (mvc) I want to change the link www.domain.com/services/item.aspx?Id=1256 to mobile.domain.com/services/1256. The problem is that I have > 10000 of pages with an absolute urls and content managers will go crazy managing this problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you are looking to for user friendly URLs in Web forms then the answer is URL Rewriting.

You can find some third party/Open source dlls for this functionality.

Let me know if I was wrong with what you require.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this article:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

I can think about 2 possible solutions, all of them requres javasctipt:

1. You have js function which will override urls on your pages
2. You have js handler which will catch  clicks and forward user to
   your server action where you'll redirect him where you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I have manually replaced the absolute urls in DB like www.domain.com/services/service.aspx?Id=1000 becomes /services/service.aspx?Id=1000 using SQL replace method. And then implemented RewritingModule using Dictionary.

```
public class RewritingModule : IHttpModule
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Инициализация
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="application"></param>
        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.BeginRequest += ApplicationBeginRequest;
        }

        private static void ApplicationBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var _httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in DictionaryRewrites)
            {
                var currentUrl = _httpContext.Request.RawUrl;
                string itemKey = item.Key;

                if (currentUrl.Equals(itemKey, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Process301Redirect(_httpContext, item.Value);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        private static Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryRewrites = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
        { 
            { "/Services/Pavilions/Item.aspx?ItemID=5", "/exhibitions/pavillions/3/hall4" },
            { "/Services/ConferenceHalls/Item.aspx?ItemID=10127", "/conferences/conferencehalls/1/conferencehall1" }

        };

        /// <summary>
        /// 301 Redirect
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="toRedirect"></param>
        private static void Process301Redirect(HttpContext context, string toRedirect)
        {
            var _localizationSettings = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<LocalizationSettings>();
            var _workContext = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>();
            var _httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
            var _webHelper = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWebHelper>();
            string applicationPath = _httpContext.Request.ApplicationPath;

            if (_localizationSettings.SeoFriendlyUrlsForLanguagesEnabled)
            {
                toRedirect = toRedirect.AddLanguageSeoCodeToRawUrl(applicationPath, _workContext.WorkingLanguage);
            }

            string str = _webHelper.GetApplicationLocation() + toRedirect;
            context.Response.AddHeader("Location", str);
            context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            //clean-up code here.
        }
    }
```